# prevent writings to document depending on user type in firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection called shared in this collection I will have a doc that will serve as a connection between admin and clients (so clients can push theirs online status so does the the admin) , what I want to make is a security rule that allows the admin to modify his filed only
(onlineAdmin : true)

and clients to modify theirs doc only (onlineClients : {clientID : true}).
can this be done using rules ? if so how to limit the writing to each of the user types and depending on what in this case ?

[Doc Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXZWW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that is totally possible and covered quite well in the Firebase documentation on [role based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access). From there come these example rules for when you define the roles in Firestore documents:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // For attribute-based access control, Check a boolean `admin` attribute
    allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
    allow read: true;

    // Alterntatively, for role-based access, assign specific roles to users
    match /some_collection/{document} {
     allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "Reader"
     allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "Writer"
   }
  }
}
```

And these rules for when you define the roles in custom attributes:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // For attribute-based access control, check for an admin claim
    allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    allow read: true;

    // Alterntatively, for role-based access, assign specific roles to users
    match /some_collection/{document} {
     allow read: if request.auth.token.reader == "true";
     allow write: if request.auth.token.writer == "true";
   }
  }
}
```

I also recommend checking out this video from a Firebase expert on the topic: [Implementing Authorization Models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyZQBC-KSuM&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLl7JUUdNWb_n23gp1N9BlJa&index=6)